# Spring Security Role Hierarchy not working using Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

First of all, I am new to Java Spring Framework. So forgive me if I did not provide enough info. I have tried to add RoleHierarchy into my app but it did not work. Below are the codes I have tried.

---

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
// These config is try to set up a user Role Hierarchy
@Bean
public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
  System.out.println("arrive public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy()");
  RoleHierarchyImpl r = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
  r.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_STAFF");
  r.setHierarchy("ROLE_STAFF > ROLE_USER");
  r.setHierarchy("ROLE_DEVELOPER > ROLE_USER");
  r.setHierarchy("ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST"); 
  return r;
}

@Bean
public AffirmativeBased defaultAccessDecisionManager(RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy){
  System.out.println("arrive public AffirmativeBased defaultAccessDecisionManager()");
  List<AccessDecisionVoter> decisionVoters = new ArrayList<>();

  // webExpressionVoter
  WebExpressionVoter webExpressionVoter = new WebExpressionVoter();
  DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler
      expressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
  expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
  webExpressionVoter.setExpressionHandler(expressionHandler);

  decisionVoters.add(webExpressionVoter);
  decisionVoters.add(roleHierarchyVoter(roleHierarchy));
  // return new AffirmativeBased(Arrays.asList((AccessDecisionVoter) webExpressionVoter));
  return new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
}

@Bean
public RoleHierarchyVoter roleHierarchyVoter(RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {
  System.out.println("arrive public RoleHierarchyVoter roleHierarchyVoter");
  return new RoleHierarchyVoter(roleHierarchy);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  // skipping some codes
  http
    // skipping some codes
    .accessDecisionManager(defaultAccessDecisionManager(roleHierarchy()))
  // skipping some codes
}
```

---

**MethodSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

  @Inject
  private SecurityConfig securityConfig;

  @Override
  protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return securityConfig.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Override
  protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
    System.out.println("arrive protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler()");
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler d = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    d.setRoleHierarchy(securityConfig.roleHierarchy());
    return d;
  }

}
```

---

And I have a `UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService` that provide the `principal`, `Authentication` and `GrantedAuthority`

Finally I have some APIs:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_STAFF')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/contactUs", method = RequestMethod.GET)

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_DEVELOPER')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/system", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

---

The problem is now if I login as ROLE_STAFF, ROLE_DEVELOPER, ROLE_ADMIN, I got the following result.

```
| API       | ROLE_STAFF | ROLE_DEVELOPER | ROLE_ADMIN |
|-----------|------------|----------------|------------|
| contactUs | 200        | 403            | 403        |
| system    | 403        | 200            | 403        |
```

As you can see `ROLE_STAFF` and `ROLE_DEVELOPER` work just fine. But I want `ROLE_ADMIN` as a super role of both and it didn't work.

FYI, I am using spring-security 3.2.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The issue is in the RoleHierachy, which should be like this:

```
@Bean
public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
  RoleHierarchyImpl r = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
  r.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_STAFF and ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_DEVELOPER and ROLE_STAFF > ROLE_USER and ROLE_DEVELOPER > ROLE_USER");
  return r;
}
```

keep calling `setHierarchy()` will override the setting before

Comment: note that using "and" is optional. For Spring ""ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_STAFF and ROLE_ADMIN" is equivalent to ""ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_STAFF ROLE_ADMIN". I prefer your notation but just saying

Comment: This actually works even if it's using optional syntax. It would be nice if it threw some kind of syntax exception because I had `A > B > C`

Comment: using "..`and`.." for Spring-security 5.6.1 is not working for men. It should be `A > B > C`

Answer (score 21):

Everytime I want to implement a hierarchy of roles with Spring Security and Java config, I use the following approach:

1. We have to add a **RoleHierarchyImpl** bean into context (You see, that I use **multiple roles** to build a hierarchy):

   ```
   @Bean
   public RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy() {
       RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
       roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_DBA ROLE_DBA > ROLE_USER ");
       return roleHierarchy;
   }
   ```
2. Then we need to create web expression handler to pass obtained hierarchy to it:

   ```
   private SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation> webExpressionHandler() {
       DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
       defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy());
       return defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler;
   }
   ```
3. The final step is to add expressionHandler into http.authorizeRequests():

   ```
           @Override
           protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
               http
                  .authorizeRequests()
                       .expressionHandler(webExpressionHandler())
                       .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("(hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_DBA')) and isFullyAuthenticated()")
                       .antMatchers("/dba").access("hasRole('ROLE_DBA') and isFullyAuthenticated()")
                       .antMatchers("/dba/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                       .and()
                  .requiresChannel()
                       .antMatchers("/security/**").requiresSecure()
                       .anyRequest().requiresInsecure()
                       .and()
                  .formLogin()
                       .loginPage("/login")
                       .failureUrl("/login?auth=fail")
                       .usernameParameter("username")
                       .passwordParameter("password")
                       .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin")
                       .permitAll()
                       .and()
                  .logout()
                           .logoutUrl("/logout")
                           .deleteCookies("remember-me")
                           .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                           .logoutSuccessUrl("/index")
                           .permitAll()
                           .and()
                  .csrf()
                           .and()
                  .rememberMe().tokenValiditySeconds(1209600)
                           .and()
                  .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
                           .and()
                  .anonymous().disable()
                  .addFilter(switchUserFilter());
           }
   ```

**Result:** in this particular example we try to visit **/dba** section after we have logged in using admin user (ROLE_ADMIN). Before we created a hierarchy, we had an access denied result, but now we can visit this section without any problems.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - it's miles better than whatever half attempt at answers I get when I search on google. Also note that for this, you need to have granted authorities as `ROLE_ADMIN`, instead of just something like `ADMIN` like I was attempting to do.

Answer (score 11):

Note: The accepted answer won't work in the newest version of Spring security (I think since release 5.2.1).
This is because the 'and' (ROLE_1 > ROLE_2 **and** ROLE_2 > ROLE_3) notation was never an official standard. You could have written every word instead of 'and' and it would still work the same in the past versions.

Instead, in the new version you should now use '\n' (new line), e.g. ROLE_1 > ROLE_2\nROLE2 > ROLE_3 ...

Answer (score 4):

For me the solution was having proper bean name for the instance of `DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler`. The name should be `webSecurityExpressionHandler`.

```
@Bean
public RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy() {
    RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    roleHierarchy.setHierarchy(Roles.getRoleHierarchy());
    return roleHierarchy;
}

@Bean
public DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler webSecurityExpressionHandler() {
    DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy());
    return expressionHandler;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .expressionHandler(webSecurityExpressionHandler())
            ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Override the `createExpressionHandler` method so it returns a configured global expression handler

```
  @Configuration
  @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
  public class GlobalMethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
      @Autowired
      private RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy;

      @Override
      protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler(){
          return methodSecurityExpressionHandler();
      }

      private DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler(){
          DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
          expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
          return expressionHandler;
      }

      @Bean
      public RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy() {
          RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
      roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_OWNER > ROLE_USER");
          return roleHierarchy;
      }

      @Bean
      public RoleHierarchyVoter roleVoter() {
          return new RoleHierarchyVoter(roleHierarchy);
      }

      @Configuration
      public static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

          @Override
          protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {}
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct format is: `ROLE_A > ROLE_B and ROLE_B > ROLE_C.` see [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/hierarchicalroles/RoleHierarchy.html#getReachableGrantedAuthorities-java.util).

```
@Bean
public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
    RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    roleHierarchy.setHierarchy(UserRole.ROLE_HIERARCHY);
    return roleHierarchy;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't use Spring RoleHierarchy - because it doea not work for me.
But Ussualy I do like this:
Define Role interface

```
public static interface Role {
  String getName();
  List<String> getHierarchy();
}
```

List of my roles (to store in DB):

```
public interface AuthStates {
  // Spring security works fine only with ROLE_*** prefix
  String ANONYMOUS = "ROLE_ANONYMOUS";
  String AUTHENTICATED = "ROLE_AUTHENTICATED";
  String ADMINISTRATOR = "ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR";
}
```

Define Anonymous role as basic role class:

```
public static class Anonymous implements Role {
  private final String name;
  private final List<String> hierarchy = Lists.newArrayList(ANONYMOUS);

  public Anonymous() {
    this(ANONYMOUS);
  }

  protected Anonymous(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @Override
  public List<String> getHierarchy() {
    return hierarchy;
  }

  protected void addHierarchy(String name) {
    hierarchy.add(name);
  }
}
```

Define Authenticated role (common user role):

```
public static class Authenticated extends Anonymous {
  public Authenticated() {
    this(AUTHENTICATED);
  }

  protected Authenticated(String name) {
    super(name);
    addHierarchy(AUTHENTICATED);
  }
}
```

Define Administrator role (at the top of the evolution):

```
public static class Administrator extends Authenticated {
  public Administrator() {
    this(ADMINISTRATOR);
  }

  protected Administrator(String name) {
    super(name);
    addHierarchy(ADMINISTRATOR);
  }
}
```

Optional - static factory class:

```
public static Role getRole(String authState) {
  switch (authState) {
    case ANONYMOUS: return new Anonymous();
    case AUTHENTICATED: return new Authenticated();
    case ADMINISTRATOR: return new Administrator();
    default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong auth state");
  }
}
```

In my CustomUserDetailsService (which implements UserDetailsService) I use role like this:

```
private Collection<GrantedAuthority> createAuthority(User user) {
  final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
  AuthStates.Role userAuthState = AuthStates.getRole(user.getAuthState());
  for (String role : userAuthState.getHierarchy()) {
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
  }
  return authorities;
}
```

[authorities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Gs7n.png)

In controllers:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_AUTHENTICATED')")
```

Will allow user logged in as ROLE_AUTHENTICATED and ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR both.