# Spring Security role hierarchy @Secured JavaConfig

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've run into some problems trying to implemented a role hierarchy in Spring Security with JavaConfig rather than XML. Is there any way to implement a role hierarchy with the @Secured annotation rather than HttpSecurity antMatchers? I cannot seem to add the role hierarchy to HttpSecurity without providing the proper String patterns, though I'd like to be able to make access decisions exclusively using @Secured.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: At least one mapping is required (i.e. authorizeRequests().anyRequest.authenticated())

@Bean
public RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy() {
    RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER");
    return roleHierarchy;
}

private SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation> webExpressionHandler() {
    DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy());
    return defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler;
}

public void configure(HttpSecurity http){
http.authorizeRequests().expressionHandler(webExpressionHandler()).and().//other stuff
}
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your RoleHierarchyImpl look like?

Comment: Edited my post. Followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888458/spring-security-role-hierarchy-not-working-using-java-config mostly, but is there any way I can get rid of the antMatchers since I just want to use @Secured annotations

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to have a role hierarchy using @Secured annotation. Found it really tricky but eventually have a following solution (groovy code).

Define your voters and decision manager in @Configuration class:

```
    @Bean
  public static RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
    RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl()
    roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("""\
        $SUPER_ADMIN > $ORGANIZATION_ADMIN
        $ORGANIZATION_ADMIN > $DOCTOR
        $DOCTOR > $NURSE
        $NURSE > $PATIENT
        $PATIENT > $USER""".stripIndent())
    roleHierarchy
  }

  @Bean
  public static RoleHierarchyVoter roleVoter() {
    new RoleHierarchyVoter(roleHierarchy())
  }

  @Bean
  public AffirmativeBased accessDecisionManager() {
    List<AccessDecisionVoter> decisionVoters = new ArrayList<>();
    decisionVoters.add(webExpressionVoter());
    decisionVoters.add(roleVoter());
    new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
  }

  private WebExpressionVoter webExpressionVoter() {
    WebExpressionVoter webExpressionVoter = new WebExpressionVoter()
    webExpressionVoter.setExpressionHandler(expressionHandler())
    webExpressionVoter
  }

  @Bean
  public DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler(){
    DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy());
    return expressionHandler;
  }
```

then in security configuration add the decision manager:

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      ...
      .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager())
      .antMatchers("/auth").permitAll()
      ...
  }
```

Then you also have to overwrite the GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration to also use your RoleHierarchyVoter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
class MethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

  @Override
  protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
   new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler(roleHierarchy: SecurityConfiguration.roleHierarchy())
  }

  @Override
  protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
    AffirmativeBased manager = super.accessDecisionManager() as AffirmativeBased
    manager.decisionVoters.clear()
    manager.decisionVoters << SecurityConfiguration.roleVoter()
    manager
  }

}
```

I'm removing other voters and just adding my RoleHierarchyVoter in AccessDecisionManager but you can keep others if you need. In my case I'm only using @Secured annotation thus don't need others. This is the part that is not mentioned anywhere to make it working with @Secured annotation.

---

Another solution is just to create a RoleHierarchy bean with hierarchy configuration and inject it into your custom authentication filter where you would authenticate the user and pass authorities to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken by calling:

```
roleHierarchy.getReachableGrantedAuthorities(authorityFromUserDetails)
```

This second solution is a bit tricky if you are not using any custom authorization but in my case it was even simpler.